# JavaFX 8 strokeText unexpected behaviour

Tags: canvas, text, javafx, rendering

strokeText uses setLineWidth for the width of the stroke. If I set the lineWidth to 0.0 however (expecting a stroke of 0.0 i.e. no stroke at all), it actually strokes the text with the previously set lineWidth. So despite an explicit gc.setLineWidth(0.0);, the stroke value is ignored and uses whatever was set previously. Here is an example:

```
    Canvas fieldCanvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
    gc = fieldCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();    

    gc.setFill(Color.YELLOW); 
    gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
    gc.setLineWidth(10.0);   

    gc.fillRect(50, 50, 350, 150);
    gc.strokeRect(50, 50, 350, 150);

    gc.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 100));                
    gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);        
    gc.setLineWidth(0.0);                               

    gc.fillText("TEST", 100, 160);
    gc.strokeText("TEST", 100, 160);
```

This will stroke the text with a value of 10.0

The JAVA FX8 documentation states: An infinite or non-positive value outside of the range (0, +inf) will be ignored and the current value will remain unchanged.

BUT that also seems to include 0 itself. So any value must be > 0 not == 0.

Should the documentation be clearer or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs could be clearer, it means exclusive range. Here's the current implementation:

```
 * Sets the current line width.
 * 
 * @param lw value in the range {0-positive infinity}, with any other value 
 * being ignored and leaving the value unchanged.
 */
public void setLineWidth(double lw) {
    // Per W3C spec: On setting, zero, negative, infinite, and NaN
    // values must be ignored, leaving the value unchanged
    if (lw > 0 && lw < Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
```

As the comment suggests, this seems to be following the Canvas spec, which behaves identically, you can try something similar in your browser -

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 30;
ctx.lineWidth = 0;
ctx.strokeRect(20, 20, 80, 100);
```

Which gives you a fat rectangle.